# Implement Custom Color Picker for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try to implement this [Color Picker](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Custom_Color_Picker_for_Windows_Phone). But I have problem with "ColorToBrushConverter".
Where and how can I add him to the project ?

Error list:

> Error 1   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'CustomColorsPicker.Converters' that could not be found.
>
> Error 2   The resource "ColorToBrushConverter" could not be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see one on the site, but you can easily write one yourself.

```
namespace MyApp.Converters
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
       private readonly SolidColorBrush MagentaBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta);

       public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var color = value as Color;
            if (color != null)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(color);
            }
            return MagentaBrush ;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```